# How to add IV to Cipher in Android?

Tags: android, encryption, bouncycastle

In my code, I specify

`val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES_128/GCM/NoPadding")`

and when I do the following code to supply my own IV

```
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, IvParameterSpec(nonceByteArray, 0, 16))
```

I get the following error saying it has to be of length 12, but I I thought the IV should be 16 if we choose AES_128?

```
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Expected IV length of 12 but was 16
```

Comment: IV and nonce are not the same thing.  Are you trying to set the nonce or IV here?

Comment: If and what kind of IV AES needs depends on the mode, `ECB` has no IV, `CBC` want's 16 bytes, `GCM` wants a unique 12 byte nonce per message

Comment: According to the specification, for GCM the IV can have any length. However, the recommended length is 12 bytes. This is the most efficient and secure (s. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/41610) and [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68525)). Implementations may differ, `AES_128/GCM/NoPadding` allows only the recommended 12 bytes IV, `AES/GCM/NoPadding` allows all IV lengths (nevertheless the 12 bytes IV generally should be used). By the way for GCM `GCMParameterSpec` should be used instead of `IvParameterSpec` (if the platform supports this).